# The difference(s) of CSS inside specific folder in Blazor and what they are for

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am very new to Blazor. Need some helps, thanks in advance.

What's the different(s) between ".css" file in "wwwroot/css"

[image]

and ".css" file inside specific file of .razor in "Shared" folder

[image]

And on what situation we use them?

Answer (score 3):

Here in your question, `MainLayout.razor.css` is an isolated CSS specific to the MainLayout component & likewise is `NavMenu.razor.css` to the NavMenu component. This is called **CSS Isolation**, where you can define component specific styles. And `site.css` in wwwroot folder is the global style for
the entire project.

you can learn more about CSS Isolation in Blazor [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)